# iOS Swift : fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to remove an object at an index but I'm getting an error. Here is my code:

```
var arr2 = [3,5,6]

let arr3 = arr2
for (index, element) in arr3.enumerated() {
    print("III \(index)")
    arr2.remove(at: index)
}
```

**LOGS** :

```
 III 0
 III 1
 III 2
 fatal error: Index out of range
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What's the point of `arr1` here? What's the point of removing objects from `arr2` one at a time? And why bother using a copy of the array?

Comment: Try printing the contents of `arr2` during each iteration to see why `index` becomes a bad value.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve? In your case, `arr3.removeAll()` would give the same result.

Comment: Many similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+array+remove+index+out+of+range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `index` value is based on `arr3`. As you remove items from `arr2` that `index` doesn't represent the proper location in `arr2`.

One solution is to iterate `arr3` in reverse.

```
for (index, element) in arr3.enumerated().reversed() {
```

This keeps the remaining indexes the same as the iteration continues.

Comment: It is counting down instead of up. If you have an array with indexes 1,2,3,4,5 and you delete index 3, you end up with an array 1,2,3,4. 3 is removed and the higher numbered items shift down. If you go backwards, you don't care about that shifting because you already processed those higher indexes.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute for-loop you get which index value to be deleted.So check below output(I made your code little simple to understand)-:

```
  import UIKit

       var arr2 = [3,5,6]

let arr3 = arr2
for (index, element) in arr3.enumerated() {
    print("III \(index)")
    arr2.remove(at: index)
}
```

**First iteration-:**

```
index = 0 and array2=[5, 6] after removing index . Now remaining index you have is [0,1].
```

**Second iteration-:**

```
index = 1 and array2=[5] after removing value at 1 . Now remaining index you have is [0].
```

**Third iteration-:**

```
index = 2 and array2=[5] what to remove at 2?? . Ok let me error out.
```

**Now execute in reverse order you will get correct index . So it works**